# Solving two-step interpolation in python and numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This problem is a little complicated, so I will try to make it as simple as possible.

Say that I have a table of values for which I want to perform two-step 1d interpolation; i.e., interpolation of a 2d value via interpolating in 1d *twice*. Note that this is a different problem from that being solved by `scipy.interpolate.interp2d`, and the appropriate algorithm is going to be quite different.

Here is an example of source data for performing the interpolation. The column labels are the dependent variable, Z. The row labels are the SECOND independent variable, Y. The 2d, interior portion of the table is the FIRST independent variable, X.

```
   Z  1  2  3
Y
1     1  2  3   <-- X row 1
2     3  4  5   <-- X row 2
```

We want to produce a factory function. The factory produces another function which, given the above source data, performs appropriate twice-interpolation of any `x,y` pair. We will call the factory function `twice_interp1d_with_2d_x`, and it will look like this;

```
def twice_interp1d_with_2d_x(x, y, z):
    """Produce an interpolating function of the form:
           f(x,y)
       The function interpolates an x and y value to a z value.
       Expects a 2d x argument. The y-axis is expected to be the rows; z is the columns."""
    ...
```

Here is the same function with type information attached (all variables are array_like; x is expected to be 2d, y and z are 1d):

```
def twice_interp1d_with_2d_x(x: array_like, y: array_like, z: array_like) -> Callable[[array_like, array_like], array_like]: ...
```

Using the existing `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` function (which includes additional `bounds_error` and `fill_value` arguments), I have already written this function (but it is broken; see below), and the basic solution works like this:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def twice_interp1d_with_2d_x(x, y, z, bounds_error=True, fill_value=None):
    interp1d_rows = [interp1d(row, z, bounds_error=bounds_error, fill_value=fill_value) for row in x]
    def interpolator(x_inner, y_inner):
        temp_z = [f(x_inner) for f in interp1d_rows]
        return interp1d(y, temp_z, bounds_error=bounds_error, fill_value=fill_value)(y_inner)
    return interpolator
```

This works for many situations:

```
>>> twice_interp1d_with_2d_x(X, Y, Z)(3, 2)
array(1.)
```

*Side note: `interp1d` always produces numpy arrays; this result is a 0d (ie, atomic) array*

But there is a big problem. Consider the case of `(x=4, y=2)`. The solution to this case should be:

```
>>> twice_interp1d_with_2d_x(X, Y, Z)(4, 2)
array(2.)
```

But instead, we get a `ValueError` because the value of 4 is beyond the upper bounds of the first row in X. We can try to fix this by passing `bounds_error=False`, but then we just get a `nan`:

```
>>> twice_interp1d_with_2d_x(X, Y, Z, bounds_error=False)(4, 2)
array(nan)
```

To make matters even more complicated, sometimes an array will be passed as the first argument or second argument, or BOTH arguments, and we might have to deal with `np.nan` for some combinations, but not others:

```
>>> twice_interp1d_with_2d_x(X, Y, Z, bounds_error=False)([3, 4], 2)
array([nan,  2.])
```

The question is: is there a simple, concise way to produce a correct version of this function using modern idiomatic python and numpy that I am overlooking? I know I could solve this using line after line of logic-- but it is going to be hours of work. Is this solvable in some quick, elegant way that I am not thinking of?

Comment: Re nans: can you make it `fill_value="extrapolate"`?

Comment: @ev-br no, if you have nans you can't extrapolate. and besides, it would give the wrong answer in some cases.

Comment: A 30 second rule applies to me, if not others.  I have about that time to read a question, and decide whether it is something I can answer right off, or whether it is intriguing enough to spend more time.  Also my answers always include working code, preferably starting with a [mcve] provided by the OP.

Comment: @hpaulj The problem is this question doesn't lend itself to much of a reproducible example. It is a complicated question. But thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 1):

What about separating the case where the requested `y` is an element of `Y`? Have a look at the snippet below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


def fun(X, Y, Z, x, y, **kwargs):
    X, Y, Z = np.asarray(X), np.asarray(Y), np.asarray(Z)
    if y in Y:
        return interp1d(X[np.nonzero(Y == y)[0][0]], Z, **kwargs)(x)
    else:
        return interp1d(Y, [interp1d(row, Z, **kwargs)(x) for row in X],
                        **kwargs)(y)


X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])
Y = np.array([1, 2])
Z = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(fun(X, Y, Z, [3, 4], 2,
          kind='linear', bounds_error=True, fill_value=None))  # [1. 2.]
print(fun(X, Y, Z, 3, 1.5,
          kind='linear', bounds_error=True, fill_value=None))  # 2.0
```